# opencv error file cannot be opened for reading cv::face::FaceRecognizer::read windows

Tags: python, django, opencv, opencv3.0, opencv-contrib

I have been trying to run a `django` application (attendance system with face recognition).
I'm using `python` with `opencv3.2` and after installing both `opencv-python` and `opencv-contrib-python` using pip on anaconda framework, i still get error like this

```
opencv error file cannot be opened for reading 
cv::face::FaceRecognizer::read".
file c:\projects\opencv-python\opencv_contrib\modules\face\src\facerec.cpp line 61.
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the the same problem. Actually problem happens here.

```
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
recognizer.read("recognizers/face-trainner.yml")//path should be correct
```

There is a path in the second line of the above code snippet. You should give the correct path for the training model and this works for me.